# Why does HtmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes delete attributes when called?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In asp.net MVC I wanted to retrieve validation attributes of certain fields.

For this I used HtmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes() method. 
The first time being called, it returns a collection of attributes as expected. However, if called a second time, attributes are empty.

example:

```
var attributes = htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(propertyName);
var attributes2 = htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(propertyName);
```

attributes2 is empty.

This is a problem for me because I check validation attributes of *fieldB* while rendering *fieldA* but then when *fieldB* is rendered, attributes are gone.

Is this a known behaviour ? Am I missing something ? How can I preserv validation attributes betweeen GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes calls ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design. `Html.ViewContext.FormContext` contains a list of the fields that it thinks have been rendered; when you call `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes` the first time it marks your field as rendered, then subsequent calls return an empty collection.

You can set that field as un-rendered by doing this:

```
Html.ViewContext.FormContext.RenderedField(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName), false);
```

Comment: I needed this for radio buttons which all bind to the same property. Watch out for prefixes. `GetUnobtrusiveAttributes` looks like it wants to work on the property without a prefix while the rendered fields are keyed _with_ the prefix so you have to use the property name including any prefix with `FormContext.RenderedField`.